# Why is my generated WHERE clause not correct?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've written the following query in SQLAlchemy:

```
session.query(matches_atp).filter(matches_atp.ID_M == 668)
```

And I'm getting a weird `WHERE` clause when I check it:

```
WHERE belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_M` = %(ID_M_1)s
```

When I switch to:

```
session.query(matches_atp).filter(matches_atp.ID_M == None)
```

Then everything looks fine:

```
WHERE belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_M` IS NULL
```

Why am I getting the `%(ID_M_1)s` instead of `668`?

If this isn't an easy answer then I'll post the code for an MRE.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Happy to accept that as an answer? Could you also give an example of how to "use placeholders in your manual "raw" queries as well (instead of inlining values to strings using formatting etc.)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a placeholder. Your DB driver will then replace it with the proper value when executing. In other words it is as expected. You should use placeholders in your manual "raw" queries as well, instead of inlining values to strings using formatting etc., which is injection and error prone. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

# Wrap with text() in order to be able to use named placeholder style no
# matter which driver is in use underneath SQLA.
stmt = text("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :bar")
engine.execute(stmt, {"bar": 1})
```

SQLAlchemy has an exception for `== None` in the query compiler that produces `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`, which would rarely, if ever, make sense.

Comment: Could you also give an example of how to "use placeholders in your manual "raw" queries as well (instead of inlining values to strings using formatting etc.)"?